# Getting connection refused to Private GKE Internal point. Autopilot private cluster

Tags: google-cloud-platform, bitbucket, devops, google-kubernetes-engine, pipeline

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G1ZRv.jpg)Getting Connection refused error in my bitbucket pipeline when it is trying to deploy manifest in GKE. Mine is a Autopilot Private Cluster. I am running this pipeline using a service account. Is it due to a permission issue. What permission it needs to authorize my user

I am just trying to do data import activity in my Bitbucket pipeline. All of a sudden I see this message when I am running my pipeline

Comment: Can you post the error you are seeing?  Also, do you have a private cluster with a private endpoint or is your endpoint public?

Comment: The error what I see is connection to the server 10.x.x.x was refused. Did you specify the right host or port ?

Comment: Also this is the private endpoint I am suspecting that this could be a permission issue any idea what permission are needed for a user to connect to autopilot gke private cluster and perform the deployment

Comment: If you use the private endpoint, you will not be able to connect from outside of your Google Cloud VPC.